# How to get a part of url from php

Tags: php

how can I use php to get exactly the id from google play url.
Example:
Google Play Url: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**com.zing.zalo**&hl=en

I want to get the **com.zing.zalo** . Thank you!

Comment: Check this [https://3v4l.org/SLkbY](https://3v4l.org/SLkbY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple Way**

> use `preg_match` or get the id from the url using `$_GET['id']`, if
>   you get this from url as other answer did.

```
$Url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zing.zalo&hl=en";
preg_match("/[^?]+(?:\?id=([^&]+).*)?/", "$Url", $matches);

echo $matches[1]; //com.zing.zalo
```

Working Example here [Check online](https://3v4l.org/SLkbY)

**The Longest way:**

Simply you can use some PHP function to get it. Lets you have the following url.

```
$Url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zing.zalo&hl=en";
```

so what you need to explode the url using `?` which is only one on the url.

```
$arr = explode("?", $Url);
```

From that array you need to store only the second part cause you need query string. So take only `$arr[1]`. Now explode again the `$arr[1]` with the `&` sign which is divide the rest of the url i mean `$arr[1]`.

```
$arr2 = explode("&", $arr[1]);
```

Now you are all set, use another `explode` function to get the **com.zing.zalo** from the `$arr2[0]`.

```
$idval = explode("=", $arr2[0]);
```

Result, Just echo the second part of the `$idval` array.

```
echo $idval[1]; //com.zing.zalo
```

Comment: Winner winner! That's the regex you want! I stopped since OP isn't even bothering trying.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I am finding! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_GET['id']` to get the query string value of `id`

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Comment: I create a function to get "com.zing.zalo", not get it from browser.
Example:
function get_id () {
$url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zing.zalo&hl=en";
$id = how_to_get_id($url);
}

Comment: @GameDayRoi what you meant by function ? can you explain further , what output you want ? whats the errors ?

Comment: I want to use php to get id "com.zing.zalo" from the above url. The same as get itune id from url like this:
<code>
$url = 'http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bring-me-sandwiches!!/id457603026?mt=8';
echo end(explode('/id', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)));
</code>

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with regex: `(?:\?id=)(.*)\b` (*I'm sure there's a more effective regex for this, but this accomplishes what you require*)

```
preg_match('/(?:\?id=)(.*)\b/', 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zing.zalo&hl=en', $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ?id=com.zing.zalo&
    [1] => com.zing.zalo
)
```

Comment: Thank you, how can i make it work with url without "&hl=en". For example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zing.zalo

Comment: @GameDayRoi check out the edit above - simply change the regex to: `(?:\?id=)(.*)\b`

Comment: I means that i just want to get the id "com.zing.zalo" exactly although the url have ''&hl=en" or not have "&hl=en"

Comment: @FrayneKonok This is the quickest way :) and stops you from having to `explode()` many times!

Comment: When I use the code above and echo $matches[1]; result is "com.zing.zalo&hl=en"

Comment: @Darren, Look what is your regex says: [https://3v4l.org/7OEB0](https://3v4l.org/7OEB0)